# Creating Dynamic Rows with Dropdown (from mysql DB) that populates textbox inside rows via Ajax Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

[image: Dynamic Rows]

In the above image i am creating dynamic rows (which is working just fine). However, I have then included the ability to populate the "Desc:" textbox based on what is selected in the dropdown to the left of "Desc:".  This works just fine for the first row but not for any other row after that. 
Here is my javascript code for the add and remove rows (working well):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

function initTemplates() {
        $('.template').each(function () {
            var template = $(this).children(),
                key = template.attr('class') || 'template' + templates.length;
            templates[key] = template;
            $(this).remove();

        });
    }

    var templates = {};
    initTemplates();

//when the Add Field button is clicked

    $("#add").click(function () {
        $('#items').append(templates['emp_detail'].clone());
    });


//function on Delete button 

    $(document).on('click', '.delete', function () {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });

});

</script>
```

Here is the code (php and HTML) for pulling data from mySQL DB and populating the dropdown:

```
<div class="template">
    <div class="emp_detail">
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){

                $("#sel_depart").change(function(){
                    var deptid = $(this).val();

                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'getUsers.php',
                        type: 'post',
                        data: {depart:deptid},
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success:function(response){

                            var len = response.length;

                            $("#sel_user").empty();
                            for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
                                var PartNumber = response[i]['PartNumber'];

                                $("#sel_user").empty().append("<input type=text value='"+PartNumber+"' size=20 name=PartNumber[]>");

                            }
                        }
                    });
                });

            });
    </script>
    <span width=100%>
    <table border="0" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width="100%">
    <tr>
    <td style='white-space:nowrap;'>
    <input type="button" class="delete" value="Delete">
    <label><font style="font-size:11px;"><b>Part: </b></label><input type="text" class="small" name="BX_ProductName[]" size="20">
    <label><font style="font-size:11px;color:#D41118;"><b>OR </font></label>

    <select name="Prod1[]" id="sel_depart">
    <option>Select Pre-Loaded Part...</option>
```

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT ProductName, id FROM table_name GROUP BY ProductName ORDER BY ProductName ASC";
$sql_result = mysql_query($sql,$connection);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result))
{
$id = $row['id']; 
$ProductName = $row['ProductName'];    
echo"<option value=\"$id\">$ProductName</option>";   
}
mysql_close($connection);
```

?>

```
    <label for="PartNumber"><font style="font-size:11px;"><b>Desc: </b></label><span id="sel_user"><input type="text" class="small" name="PartNumber[]" size="20"></span>
    <label for="AmountOrdered"><font style="font-size:11px;"><b>Qty: </b></label><input type="text" required="required" class="small"  name="AmountOrdered[]" size="5">
    <label for="build"><font style="font-size:11px;"><b>Build#: </b></label><input type="text" required="required" class="small"  name="build[]" size="10">
    <label for="unit_cost"><font style="font-size:11px;"><b>Unit$: </b></label><input type="text" class="small"  name="unit_cost[]" size="10">
    <label for="total_cost"><font style="font-size:11px;"><b>Total$: </b></label><input type="text" class="small"  name="total_cost[]" size="10">
    <label><font style="font-size:11px;"><b>Date: </b></label><input type="text" class="emp_from" name="ExpectedDate[]" size="10">

    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </span>

    </div>
</div>

<div id="items">
</div>
```

Here is the getUsers.php file:

```
$host = "localhost"; /* Host name */
$user = "username"; /* User */
$password = "password"; /* Password */
$dbname = "db_name"; /* Database name */

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password,$dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$con) {
 die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$departid = $_POST['depart']; 

$sql = "SELECT id, PartNumber FROM table_name WHERE id = ".$departid;

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$users_arr = array();

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {

    $PartNumber = $row['PartNumber'];
    $userid = $row['id'];

    $users_arr[] = array("PartNumber" => $PartNumber);
}

// encoding array to json format
echo json_encode($users_arr);
```

Comment: I suspect that you do not have a unique ID for each text input, or if you do, you aren't setting the JS handler for any other than the first row. Every form element should have a unique ID or be part of an array. Each field must also have either a unique name or be part of an array in order to be posted (ajax or otherwise).

Comment: I see what you are saying. Prior to adding the auto-populated dropdown, I was able to dynamically add several rows (the dropdown used to be a textbox that I would fill in) and was able to pass all data in each textbox to another page that would insert all rows into a database table. So, when that was happening, wasn't that already doing what you are describing for all those fields? I thought that changing a textbox to a dropdown would still allow the form to be handled the same way.

Comment: Adding an input element and accessing it are entirely different. Also, after adding an element, if you need an event handler, you have to assign it after the element is added to the DOM. If when you add the element, you do not assign it a unique ID, it won't have one. Same for any event handlers.